# What is a month when it comes to Twitter API 2 limits?

Tags: twitter, twitter-api-v2

In the free tier of Twitter API v2, there's a limit of 1,500 tweets per month. Is this month a calendar month or a rolling 30-day period from the first tweet?

The documentation regarding Twitter API v2's free tier mentions a limit of 1,500 tweets per month, but it doesn't provide a clear definition of what constitutes a "month" in this context. I've looked at discussions and documentation but they do not specify the exact definition of a month:

- [Twitter Community Discussion](https://twittercommunity.com/t/understanding-the-read-limit-for-twitter-apis-free-tier/193867)
- [Twitter Developer Platform](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api)
- [MUO - Twitter’s New API Access Tiers: Pricing and Features Compared](https://www.makeuseof.com)
- [Gearrice - The free Twitter API will allow you to create up to 1,500 tweets per month](https://www.gearrice.com)